# Synonym zu „keine Reue zeigen“

Tags: synonym

> Zu viele Menschen „leben“ fast schon davon, anderen zu schaden und konsequent *keine Reue zu zeigen*, selbst wenn sie sonst nichts vorzeigen können, einen guten Beitrag einer Gesellschaft zu leisten.

Wie kann man *keine Reue zeigen* noch ausdrücken? Durch *kalt sein*?

Comment: I was very annoyed by the first paragraph. It now occurs to me that is is possibly a quote about which you have a question. If so, please mark it as such.

Comment: Wenn du eine bessere Formulierung suchst für etwas, was du sagen möchtest, dann beschreibe doch vielleicht mal mit mehr Worten, was du an der Stelle wirklich sagen möchtest. Du gibst uns zwar den ganzen Kontext,was gut ist, aber warum du mit "keine Reue zeigen" an dieser Stelle im Text nicht glücklich bist und was du eigentlich sagen möchtest, wird trotzdem nicht richtig klar.

Comment: imgur.com/a/r760ILK

Comment: [link](https://imgur.com/a/r760ILK)

Comment: Mein größtes und vielleicht einziges Problem ist die Schadenfreude von 99 % der Weltbevölkerung (ich beruhige mich mit "das ist nur ein Selektionsvorteil"). Es ist ein markantes Merkmal unzivilisierter Menschen, eine Voraussetzung, niemals als zivilisiert zu gelten. Zuviele Menschen "leben" fast schon davon, anderen zu schaden und konsequent keine Reue zu zeigen, selbst wenn sie sonst nichts vorzeigen können, einen guten Beitrag einer Gesellschaft zu leisten. Beim Verhaltentsentzug entwickeln sich psychotische Züge. Trifft hier echt auf alle zu. Gewissenslosigkeit auch.

Answer (score 1):

Ein gewisser Widerspruch zwischen der Motivation der Frage (das Salbadern über Schadenfreude) und der Frage selbst, nach Synonymen von "keine Reue zeigen", läßt mich vermuten, daß die Frage selbst nicht richtig gestellt ist (und, bevor in den Kommentaren gejammert wird, daß die Frage nicht beantwortet ist, deshalb nicht schlüssig beantwortet werden kann - eine mögliche Antwort auf eine Frage kann nunmal auch sein, daß die Frage falsch gestellt ist).

Für den Fall, daß "Schadenfreude" mit dem Mangel an Reue (beziehungsweise deren Zeigen) gleichgesetzt wird: dies ist mitnichten der Fall. Wenn ich jemanden umbringe und es mir danach nicht leid tut, dann habe bzw. *zeige* ich *keine Reue*. *Schadenfreude* hingegen ist, wenn ich mich über das Schicksal eines solchen Opfers (nicht notwendigerweise mein eigenes) lustig mache.

Falls der gesamte motivierende Absatz überflüssig und das Anliegen tatsächlich nur die Frage nach Synonymen für "keine Reue zeigen" war (in dem Falle sollte der einleitende Absatz der Frage gelöscht werden), dann stellt sich die Frage, in welchem Zusammenhang das Synonym gebraucht werden soll. In einem Erzähltext könnte etwa *Ich warf ihn raus und er ging mit Tränen in den Augen. Ich arbeitete weiter, als wäre nichts geschehen* eine gute Umschreibung für Reuelosigkeit sein. In anderen Zusammenhängen sollte man besser zu einem weniger ausholenden Synonym greifen.

Außerdem hat "reuelos" ein paar Konnotationen, die das Synonym besser abbilden sollte: *ich habe geheiratet und es nie bereut* ist ebenso "reuelos" wie *er zeigte nicht die geringste Reue ob seiner schrecklichen Tat*, hat aber dennoch einen anderen Beigeschmack.

> Reu(e)los
> kalt
> kaltherzig
> ohne Gewissensbisse (zu empfinden)
> ... als wäre nichts geschehen ...
> unberührt/ungerührt (von der Tat)
> ohne/mit wenig/... Bedauern
> ohne Regung/regungslos (das vielleicht nur bedingt)
> habe/hat (es) nie bereut

plus ein paar andere Varianten, die schon anderen Antworten und Kommentaren genannt worden sind.

Answer (score 0):

- *die Reue — das Empfinden von Schuld*
- *Reue zeigen — sich entschuldigen und Wiedergutmachung leisten*
- *etwas bereuen — eine nicht mehr rückgängig zu machende Entscheidung rückgängig machen wollen*

Answer (score 0):

Synonyme für 'keine Reue zeigend' sind sowas wie 'ohne Reue', 'reulos', 'ohne Bedauern', 'ohne schlechtes Gewissen', 'ohne Gewissensbisse'.

Denkbar wären auch Worte, die nicht 100% synonym sind wie empathielos oder kaltherzig oder rücksichtslos, gewissenlos, oder auch einfach nur egoistisch oder auch asozial. Es kommt ein wenig darauf an welche Sinnrichtung im Sinne von mitschwingenden Wertungen gewünscht ist.